# Calculating the trimmed mean as an estimator

Tags: estimation, estimators, trimmed-mean, central-tendency

My book provides the following steps to calculate the $ 100 \alpha$ percent trimmed mean for a sample data of $n$ measurments:

> 1-Order the measurments.
>
> 2-Discard the smallest $100\alpha$ percent and the largest $100\alpha$ percent of the measurments.
>
> 3-Compute the arthimetic mean of the remaining measurments.

Could one explain these steps preferably with an example.

Comment: The data are 51 3 4 1 2. Order them 1 2 3 4 51. The 20% trimmed mean ignores 1 and 51 and is the mean of 2 3 4, so 3.

Comment: Discarding an equal fraction in each tail is a common choice but not fundamental to the idea. There is literature on trimmed means with discarding in one tail only.

Comment: In your example, do we multiply $20 \%$ by $ n = 5$ to know that we need to discard just one value from each side? @NickCox

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: Alright thank you ! @NickCox should I delete the post?

Comment: Up to you. Much more at https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=st0313

Answer (score 1):

Using R, to illustrate a 10% trimmed mean of a sample of size $n = 20$ from $\mathsf{Pois}(\lambda = 30).$

```
set.seed(2020)
x = rpois(20, 30)
mean(x)
[1] 30.75
```

The regular (untrimmed) sample mean is $\bar X = 30.75.$

```
x.sort = sort(x)
x.sort
 [1] 21 23 24 26 27 28 28 30 30 30
[11] 31 31 32 32 32 33 34 36 37 50
```

10% of $n = 20$ is 2, so temporarily disregard the first two
and the last 2 observations:

```
x.temp = x.sort[3:18]
x.temp
 [1] 24 26 27 28 28 30 30 30 31 31
[11] 32 32 32 33 34 36
```

Take the mean of the remaining (central) sixteen observations.

```
mean(x.temp)
[1] 30.25
```

So the 10% trimmed mean of the sample `x` is $30.25.$

Finally, all in one step, with `trim` parameter:

```
mean(x, trim=.1)
[1] 30.25
```

However, the original sample `x` remains unchanged:

```
length(x)
[1] 20
mean(x)
[1] 30.75
```

*Notes:* (1) The 50% trimmed mean is the median:

```
median(x)
[1] 30.5
mean(x, trim=.5) 
[1] 30.5
```

(2) Caution: If the 'trimming fraction' of the sample does not amount to an integer number of observations to ignore, then R will down-weight an extreme value at each end.
[You should know that this happens, in case you get unexpected
results. But trying to emulate the exact result by hand computation might be frustrating.]

```
mean(x, trim=.08);  mean(x, trim=.1)
[1] 30.22222
[1] 30.25
```